# Why is the prefix "and" omitted before "servant" in Exodus 20:9?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, parashas-yisro

> וְיוֹם֙ הַשְּׁבִיעִ֔י שַׁבָּ֖ת לַֽיהוָ֣ה אֱלֹהֶ֑יךָ לֹֽא־תַעֲשֶׂ֨ה כָל־מְלָאכָ֜ה אַתָּ֣ה ׀ וּבִנְךָ֣ וּבִתֶּ֗ךָ **עַבְדְּךָ֤** וַאֲמָֽתְךָ֙ וּבְהֶמְתֶּ֔ךָ וְגֵֽרְךָ֖ אֲשֶׁ֥ר בִּשְׁעָרֶֽיךָ׃
>
> But the seventh day is a sabbath unto *Hashem* thy God, in it thou shalt not do any manner of work, thou, nor thy son, nor thy daughter, nor thy man-servant, nor thy maid-servant, nor thy cattle, nor thy stranger that is within thy gates.

[Exodus 20:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0220.htm#9), quoted above, contains a list of nouns, each with the prefix vov, meaning "and" (e.g., son, daughter, stranger).  But there is no vov before avdecha (your servant).  Why is there no vov before this noun?

Comment: Notably, in the parallel verse in Deuteronomy ([5:13](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0505.htm#13)) there is a vav there.

Comment: I spaced the quote up and hope the answer is clear - there are two groups: 1, your family 2. your possessions

Comment: @AlBerko You can't change a direct quotation without indicating as much.

Comment: @Al You should rather write your version as an answer - preferably with sources